# how to send authorization in <a> tag

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

i am working on a angular project and in that i am using bootstrap in html. in one element i am using  and in its href i am passing a sensitive url(payment Url) so with that i want to pas access token/authorisation token of user for saftey purpose. So is there a way to do so in html or ts file

i tried setting href and authorisation from ts file using document.getElementById but was not successfull in that

HTML:

```
<a id="payOnline(x.courseId)"[href]="paytmUrl"(click)="payOnline(x.courseId)"  [hidden]="isEnrollDisabled(x.isEnrolled)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Pay Online</a>
```

TS CODE:

```
  payOnline(courseId){
this.paytmUrl = "http://localhost:8080/payment/"+courseId + "/" + this.comservice.myUserId;
    (document.getElementById("payOnline" + courseId) as HTMLAnchorElement).href = this.paytmUrl; 
      }
```

as i set href tag dynamically from ts is there a way to set authorization also like this?

Answer (score 0):

first change the anchor tag with some-other tag or button else it will route you directly after clicking it.after clicking the button call the method like you are doing now.
for authorization you can use the JWT token and add it in your http call like below.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token' //use your token here
  })
};
```

this.http.post('your url', payload, httpOptions)

Comment: but i want it specifically for anchor tag